# Resize /boot in LVM

Tags: boot, gparted, lvm

I'm trying to resize my `/boot` partition because Ubuntu is complaining every time when it wants to install a new kernel that there isn't enough space.

So I made a live stick with the current GNOME Ubuntu and tried to resize my `/dev/sda2` with gparted. Although it seems to have problems with LVM. I can't expand the LVM in order to resize the partitions. It isn't even mounted.

[image: can't expand lvm]

I forgot to mention, that the Live USB runs with GNOME... The actual OS on my laptop is just Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that matters.

Comment: Try this [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume?rq=1). Another instance of the problem occurs [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227905/cant-resize-lvm-p2-boot-partition-even-from-live-cd?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Try Neon Developer Edition CD (https://neon.kde.org/download)

- Install KDE Partition Manager using `sudo apt install partitionmanager`

KDE Partition Manager can resize LVM PVs that are members of LVM VG.