# can't resize ubuntu partitions

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I have a single partition for Ubuntu and I would like to resize it so I can install Windows alongside Ubuntu. The problem is when I boot the Ubuntu installation disk and run GParted my partition is full however it's not, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You've seen this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: You can try [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227905/cant-resize-lvm-p2-boot-partition-even-from-live-cd) or [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume).

Comment: It's clearly full.

Answer (score 1):

The physical partition /dev/sda2 is a container for the logical partition /dev/sda5.

Follow the steps below:

1. Right click over the partition /dev/sda5 LVM - Logical Volume Management and choose the option "Resize/Move" from context menu.
2. Set the field "Free Space After" in megabytes to release some space. The field "Free Space Before" is 0 because the logical partition is using all physical partition /dev/sda2.
3. Create a new Logical partition into /dev/sda2 physical partition, or...
4. Resize the physical /dev/sda2 releasing free space to create your new Physical partition to Windows.

Some partitions perform more operations when unmounted and inactives, but you'll need a bootable USB pendrive or a Live DVD.